# Local Storage with composite objects

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have 2 sencha-models.

1st is Profile
2nd is category

One profile contains many categories.

I will be saving the data in the browser's cache with the local storage proxy.

Do I simply need to save the Profile or would I need to read and save every category too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the Local Storage system is designed in a way that composition is working correctly and dynamic array too.

Just save the top level model and it will work fine.